# Receiving NotSupportedException with CSCore audio library

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm trying to get the default audio endpoint using CSCore (https://github.com/filoe/cscore) running in Unity and I'm receiving a `System.NotSupportedException`. I'm testing this with the Unity NUnit test framework. Strangely, when running the code in the editor it works, but builds receive this exception. Can somebody explain why this is occurring?

The builds I'm doing are x64, and I checked that the DLL I'm using has been built for both x86 and x64. I'm using the 1.2.0 Release DLL. The test code and exception stack trace are provided below:

```
[Test]
public void GetAudioEndpoint_Default_NoException()
{
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(delegate ()
    {
        var deviceEnumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        var device = deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
    });
}
```

```
GetAudioEndpoint_Default_NoException (0.039s)
---
Expected: No Exception to be thrown
  But was:  <System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
  at (wrapper cominterop) CSCore.CoreAudioAPI.MMDeviceEnumerator+MMDeviceEnumeratorObject..ctor()
  at CSCore.CoreAudioAPI.MMDeviceEnumerator.CreateMmDeviceEnumerator () [0x00000] in <b6880cc671004d3aa0cc66420dbddb79>:0 
  at CSCore.CoreAudioAPI.MMDeviceEnumerator..ctor () [0x00000] in <b6880cc671004d3aa0cc66420dbddb79>:0 
  at CSCore.Tests.DeviceTests+<>c.<GetAudioEndpoint_Default_NoException>b__0_0 () [0x00001] in ***\DeviceTests.cs:13 
  at NUnit.Framework.Constraints.ThrowsConstraint+VoidInvocationDescriptor.Invoke () [0x00001] in <59819be142c34115ade688f6962021f1>:0 
  at NUnit.Framework.Constraints.ThrowsConstraint+ExceptionInterceptor.Intercept (System.Object invocation) [0x0000a] in <59819be142c34115ade688f6962021f1>:0 >
---
at CSCore.Tests.DeviceTests.GetAudioEndpoint_Default_NoException () [0x00001] in ***\DeviceTests.cs:11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason ended up being that although my scripting runtime version was .NET 4.X, my API Compatibility level was still set to 2.0. This meant that Unity was leaving out required .NET 4.X dependencies that CSCore relied upon.

The **correct** configuration, accessed from Player settings:

[image: Solution]